# Change background color of vuetify v-text-field

Tags: vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I have a login form with two text fields and a button. The background is a very light blue and I want the input fields to be white. For some reason, they stay transparent no matter what I try.

[image: Input form with focused input field]

Here is the template for the email field:

```
<v-text-field
    v-model="email"
    color="primary"
    label="E-Mail"
    variant="outlined"
>
</v-text-field>
```

The `color="primary"` will change the color of the outline whenever the field is focused.

How can I make the input fields white?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it's said in the [Documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#props-bg-color),

You can use `bg-color` to change the background of the `v-text-field`.

In short, you can add background color in your text field by doing..

```
<v-text-field
    v-model="email"
    color="primary"
    label="E-Mail"
    variant="outlined"
    bg-color="white" <!-- Add here. -->
>
</v-text-field>
```

[Demo](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Don't know why I oversaw that.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a 'style' prop

```
<template>
  <v-text-field
    v-model="email"
    color="primary"
    label="E-Mail"
    variant="outlined"
    :style="{ background: 'white' }"
  ></v-text-field>
</template>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will also make the notification area below the actual input field white.